# How to copy partial templates in BlurAdmin/angular.js using gulp serve:dist

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I'm quite new in terms of gulp, but what I need is to deploy my BlurAdmin panel (https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin) to production with partial templates just copied and not embedded into js files.

When I launch:
gulp serve:dist
I get my results in "release" folder and everything works file. How can I modify build.js file to copy all *.html partial templates (i.e. https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin/blob/master/src/app/pages/dashboard/blurFeed/blurFeed.html) to release folder without embedding them into app-caf1fdab53.js or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why -1, as I mentioned I'm rookie in gulp.

I solved it even better as I originally wanted. In directive file, instead of static html file I added URL my my REST service and I serve HTML files from there

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.dashboard')
      .directive('dashboardKafkaEvents', [ function dashboardKafkaEvents() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'mc',
      templateUrl: http://hostname:port/template/mytemplate
    };
  }])
})();
```